# Responding to an "enter" keypress within an <input> field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

My question is about handling Enter key press.I have one page called "order.aspx" which is residing inside master page.Here i am explaining the control structure

```
1. <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="420px" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>

2. <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

3. one asp grid control with one column containing textbox for entering order quantity 

4. <asp:Button ID="btnOrder" runat="server" OnClick="btnOrder_Click" />.
```

My requirement is,

1. while user enter text in the search textbox and press enter key then btnSearch_Click should fire
2. while user enter quantity in the grid textbox and press enter key then btnOrder_Click should fire.

I tried with different code finally got answers but it is not fully functional.Follwing is the javascript code i have used.

```
function DoEnterKeyButtonClick(buttonId) {
     e = event;
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if (code == 13) {
         document.getElementById('ctl00_CphMaster_' + buttonId).click();
         return false;
     }
}
```

I am calling this method on key press of txtSearch and grid textbox and passing the Button id to fire event btnSearch and btnOrder respectively.When i am entering the text in the search textbox and hitting the enter key then btnSearch_Click is firing and when i am entering the order quantity and hitting the enter key the btnOrder_Click is firing.But the issue is,after changing the page index say second page the required functionality not working.That is when i am entering order quantity and hitting the enter key then btnSearch_Click will fire first , then btnOrder_Click firing.This will clear the quantity entered and results in error.Please help me...

Thanks,
Joby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of giving this `document.getElementById('ctl00_CphMaster_' + btnSearch).click();`

Try this `document.getElementById('<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>').click();`

or try using jquery

```
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#btnSearch").click();
    }
});
```

Else place your controls inside the asp:panel and set the DefaultButton property as btnSearch as like below

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="420px" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Hope this will help.

Many Thanks
Anna

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't know what exactly this even is.
Try it like this

```
function DoEnterKeyButtonClick(event,buttonId){}
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep the following handy snippet around..

```
function getIntKey(key) {
    var keycode;
    if (key == null) { keycode = event.keyCode; } else { keycode = key.keyCode; }
    return keycode;
}
```

And use it, like this..

```
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function(e){
  if(getIntKey(e) == 13){
     //Enter was pressed, do somthing
  }
});
```